# What minimum FPS should be in XNA Windows Phone 7 application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

What minimum FPS I should keep in Windows Phone 7 XNA application?
I know that maximum of 30 fps is perfect but what are reasonable minimum values?
Assume that there is constant movement, so lag needs to be almost unnoticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frame rate is capped at 30 for Windows Phone 7 XNA applications, by default.  I would suggest that around 20-25FPS would be acceptable, but ideally, the higher the better.  It depends on how intensive your application is as to how much the FPS is affected.

Answer (score 1):

I've done J2ME games on crappy phones in the past. We were aiming for 8-12 FPS for high quality 2D games.

It didn't feel very responsive though at 8 fps. 15 fps should give you a playable game.

Of course, for this to be true, you must implement all your logic as functions of the elapsed time, not with hardcoded rates...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question can only ever be specific to a specific application.

You'll need to test on actual devices (recommend the Surround or Trophy as these have the least RAM & ROM) and then set it as high as you can without affecting performance/usability.

Comment: I'm testing this on HTC HD7, it has 512 RAM ~same as Surround and Trophy. Minimum for WP7 is 256 and there can be a problem. For now I don't see device with 256... but this is of course not good assumption.

Comment: @Paweł Smejda  I'd seen reports that the trophy and surround had less ram, but specs on HTC website say not. There are currently no devices I'm aware of that only have 256MB RAM

Comment: I'm not using much textures so 256 should be enough. But this is only assumption.

Answer (score -1):

Ok... let's define this...

'cartoon **animation**' = '3d **animation**' (imho)..

### Now let's talk about cartoons:

1. Some Japan animators make cartoons with 8 fps.. and those cartoons look pretty good... look at "school rumble" [School Rumble](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=School%20Rumble)
2. There is a cases where 200 fps is not enough. For example, two characters slowly moving into each other and kissing... remember this.. slower action = more FPS you have to provide, to make it look realistic
3. Some proffesional animators can handle 'variable' FPS.. drawing 1FPS for statick scence, and 12-24 FPS for dynamic scence.

PS : There is a lot of other tricks.. i recomend you to read some books about 2D animation..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_animation#Techniques

## So the answer is

6-8 fps is enouth, but you really have to use a lot of 'tricks' to make it look smooth...